# Proof of $f(X)\backslash f(B) \subseteq f(X\backslash B)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I think I can do this proof.  I think it's the following:

Let $y\in f(X)\backslash f(B)$.

$\implies y=f(a)$ for some $a \in X$, and $y\neq f(b)$ for any $b\in B$.

$\implies a \in X \backslash B \implies f(a)=y\in f(X\backslash B)$.

$\implies f(X)\backslash f(B) \subseteq f(X\backslash B)$.

However what I'm stuck with is the reverse.  Please can you try and explain to me at what point does the proof in reverse fail and why?

This is how I see the proof in reverse going (although I know it cannot be correct).

Let $y\in f(X\backslash B)$.

$\implies y=f(a)$ for some $a \in X \backslash B$.

$\implies a \in X$ but $a$ is not in $B \implies f(a) \in f(X)$ but $f(a)$ is not in $f(B)$.

$\implies f(a)\in f(X\backslash B)$.

$\implies y\in f(X\backslash B)$.

Comment: The error is $a\in X\setminus B \not\Rightarrow f(a) \notin f(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of $f(X)\backslash f(B)\subseteq f(X\backslash B)$ is correct.

For the reverse inclusion, your conclusion that $f(a)\not\in f(B)$ is wrong. There could still be some $b\in B$ ($a\not=b$) such that $f(b)=y=f(a)$.

From this you can also see that if $f$ is **injective** (that is, $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$), then the inclusion $f(X\backslash B)\subseteq f(X)\backslash f(B)$ holds.

Comment: ...(and thus, equality)

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion $f(X \setminus B) \subseteq f(X) \setminus f(B)$ is definitely not true.

The problem in your argument is that $a \notin B$ does not imply $f(a) \notin f(B)$, since there may be $b \in B$ satisfying $f(a) = f(b)$. The possible non-injectivity of $f$ is what makes things go wrong.

For instance, if $X = \mathbb R$, $B = [0,\infty)$, and $f(x) = x^2$, Then $f(X \setminus B) = (0,\infty)$, but $f(X) \setminus f(B) = \emptyset$.